# BAT Shutdown with countdown delay

Tags: batch-file, countdown, shutdown

Windows 7 CMD.exe style Batch

I am unsure this will work flawlessly.  I feel there will be times when the TIMEOUT finishes and the bat executes the SHUTDOWN -ABORT on it's own.  I want the user to simply press one key to stop the shutdown countdown (ideally just the COMMENT "OK" button would be enough), otherwise to flawlessly shutdown the computer.

```
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" ("C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 %10 vlc://quit) else goto end
shutdown -s -t 120 -c "Press any key in the Command Prompt to cancel the shutdown."
timeout -t 120
shutdown -a
```

I considered adding a PING 999.999.999.999 -n 1 -w 1000 to force a short wait, but if the user presses a key then it would wait before aborting the shutdown and that could also lead to a problem.

Comment: Change this `start "C:\Program Files\GlovePIE045Free\piefree.exe"` to `start "" "C:\Program Files\GlovePIE045Free\piefree.exe"` as the first quoted term is used as the window title.  `""` is then used as a null title.

Comment: Yeah, I tried `start "" "C:\Program Files\GlovePIE045Free\piefree.exe" -"C:\Program Files\GlovePIE045Free\CustomScripts\xbox360VLCremote.PIE" /tray`
but it returned with [-"C:\Program is not a valid program]

Comment: wait, I just tried it and it ran both programs (yay) but VLC didn't make a playlist, only ran whichever file was used to drag the whole pile.

Comment: What does `piefree` do?

Comment: I found it as a way to use my wireless controller to command VLC.
(https://code.google.com/p/xbox-360-vlc-remote/)

Comment: ok.  Well VLC has no commands to make a playlist, has it?  It's just playing the media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses `Choice` to provide the delay and an errorlevel to check, so that it will abort if C is pressed.  It also provides an extra option to shutdown immediately.

Timeout doesn't provide an errorlevel on abort so pressing any key to abort doesn't seem to be an option.

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" ("C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 %10 vlc://quit) else (goto :EOF)
choice /c CS /D S /T 120 /M "Waiting for 120 seconds: Press C to cancel shutdown, or S to shutdown now"
if errorlevel 2 shutdown -s
```

Comment: Won't this just shutdown after the 120 seconds, regardless of whether the user presses any key or not?

Comment: This works great, thank you.  I edited my post before I saw this, having trouble with adding another program to launch.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the [choice command](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php). You may need to download it, depending on your OS.

This will wait 300 seconds before shutting down, if `q` is not pressed.

```
choice /c aq /n /d a /t 300 /m "Computer shutting down in 300 seconds [q to cancel]"
if %errorLevel%==1 shutdown -a
```

Comment: Not a problem - Could you please mark one of the answers as correct so this question doesn't stay open?

Comment: Sorry about that, was hoping to get a response to the other issue, I made it it's own question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151408/bat-start-w-command-recognized