# BAT START w/ command recognized

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

My ultimate goal is:

- Drag & Drop video selection onto batch file
- VLC runs with selection as the playlist and closes at the end
- GlovePIE loads simultaneously and runs the script
- Computer shuts down when VLC closes
- User can cancel the shutdown with one key (two is fine)

I tried to put this together but it fails miserably...  The GlovePIE syntax does not work with a START operation, but I do not know of another way to run both programs at the same time.  I tried making a bat that runs VLC.bat and GlovePIE.bat but I don't know how to pass variables between the Launcher.bat and VLC.bat.  Anyways, having it all as a single bat seems like a better idea to me...

---

What I have so far:

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" (
start "" "C:\Program Files\GlovePIE045Free\piefree.exe" -"C:\Program Files\GlovePIE045Free\CustomScripts\xbox360VLCremote.PIE" /tray
start /wait "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 %10 vlc://quit
) else (goto :EOF)
taskkill /f /im piefree.exe
cls
choice /c CP /D P /T 120 /M "Waiting for 120 seconds: Press C to cancel shutdown, or P to power off now"
if errorlevel 2 shutdown -s
```

This is loading GlovePIE properly but multiple video's are not being noticed.

Comment: A good technique for debugging batch files is to put an `echo` in front of the line that's giving you trouble.  Often you'll find there was an error in a variable expansion, or that you needed to surround something in double-quotes (*eg* if a filename/path has spaces in it).

Comment: Oh my... the problem was I did not have a title for the `START` VLC line...  added `""` and it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this, but I'd try

```
start /wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" %* vlc://quit
```

Note: extra pair of quotes. This sets the title of the `START`ed session, otherwise the first `"quoted string"` is used.

`%*` means `allcommand-line arguments`. `%10` is invalid, only `%1..%9` are available. `%10` would be interpreted as `%1` with `0` appended.

---

Further thought: If it fails when placed in a block (parenthesised sequence of statements) then clasically, restructure the code, but you could try

```
for /f "delims=" %%z in ("%*") do start /wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" %%z vlc://quit
```

(theory : there are <kbd>)</kbd> in the parameters being passed)

Comment: oooooh, that's why I would get an odd output of the first filename. Thank you.  The line works on it's own, but when I put it inside of the () it does not load more than one movie.  =(

Answer (score 0):

This is the completed and working code.  Thanks everyone for the help.

```
@echo off
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" (
start "" "C:\Program Files\GlovePIE045Free\piefree.exe" -"C:\Program Files\GlovePIE045Free\CustomScripts\xbox360VLCremote.PIE" /tray
start /wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" %* vlc://quit
) else (goto :EOF)
taskkill /f /im piefree.exe
cls
choice /c CP /D P /T 120 /M "Waiting for 120 seconds: Press C to cancel shutdown, or P to power off now"
if errorlevel 2 shutdown -s
```